# Three gauge bosons vertex

Tags: standard-model, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

I was told that two $Z$ bosons could not decay to one (virtual) $Z$ boson at any loop level. Is it true? if so, why?

Does it also hold for photons?

Could we generalise the statement to "There cannot exist diagrams with ONLY a odd number of $Z/\gamma$"?

Comment: Can you fulfill energy and momentum conversation with that $2\to 1$ process? I mean, you can't have a single photon going into an electron and a positron for similar reasons.

Comment: $Z^*\leftrightarrow ZZ$ , * meaning virtual particle (off shell)

Comment: Yeah, that's there reason it can't happen then. You can have the vertex *inside* a larger diagram, but in an actual physical process, the incoming and outgoing states are on-shell.

Comment: Sorry, what I was told is that such a process is forbidden even inside a larger diagram, in analogy to the one consisting in two photons decaying into one single photon through a fermionic triangle loop. So I was told wrong, and this diagram does not vanish *in* a larger one?

Answer (score 2):

This is nonperturbatively true for odd number of photons because the electromagnetic lagrangian is invariant under charge conjugation implies that the electromagnetic gauge field is odd and any VEV of an odd product of time ordered gauge fields must be zero as a consequence of this discrete symmetry. This result is known as Furry's theorem.

As for odd Z's I don't know a direct reason why odd Z should vanish, because Electroweak lagrangian is not invariant under charge conjugation. But people study these trilinear neutral gauge couplings to probe new physics, take a look at http://arxiv.org/abs/0901.0260 for instance

Comment: Thanks for the answer for $\gamma$s and for the reference also which is very appropriate.